# How to add embedded binaries to a IOS framework

Tags: ios, alamofire

Hi I'm making an IOS framework.

I want to add [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to my Framework.

I'm trying to add it [manualy](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manually).

But there is no "embedded binaries" section in my target.

So how can i add it to my project?

Thanks